# Take Sql server Database backup on network drive

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have created a Database backup job on sql server 2005 and this job is creating daily backup on sql server.

But I want it will take the backup on network drive or location, when I am giving network location path like `\\erpserver\d:\backup\` .

But it is giving me an error:

```
18204.security:16 state 1.
```

Comment: This post has some answers which could match for your issue http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/cba004e5-645c-4d13-98d3-32fb173a4fa8/nitely-backups-failing-error-18204-severity-16-state-1-and-error-3041-severity-16-state

Answer (score 0):

I think that your sql user under which the back up job is run doesn't have permissions to write to the netwok folder. Agent jobs are executed not under your user but under sql server user.

This is a very common problem and microsoft has a kb article on solving it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646329